# Vue-cli: how to use pictures' paths from local json as src

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have a json file with this structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "address": "require(./assets/pic1.jpg)"
  }
]
```

I import it:

```
import data from "./assets/test.json"
```

And then try to use as src for my image:

```
<img :src='item.address'>
```

But image doesn't appear. Could anybody say how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by changing your json file and image element:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "address": 'pic1.jpg'
  }
]

<img :src="require(`./assets/${item.address}`)" >
```

See more here:
https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/202